# Specific generic type of lists within a list

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, generic-collections

I have a list of lists.

I would like to know how I can restrict the generic types of each of the inner lists so each element of the outer list contains an inner list that can only contain one type of object. So far I have tried this:

```
List<ArrayList<?>> l = new ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>();
```

But there are ways to add types of objects to the inner lists which do not belong. Is there a way to specify the type the inner list accepts?

For example, if I have the following inner lists,

```
ArrayList<T1> innerList = new ArrayList<T1>();
ArrayList<T2> innerList2 = new ArrayList<T2>();
ArrayList<T3> innerList3 = new ArrayList<T3>();
```

How would I create an outer list which can contain all of the inner lists while retaining the specific type that the inner list contains.

Also I am not sure if this is possible, or if what I am doing is bad design. If it is bad design, insight onto a better design (maybe there is a different collection that does this better) would be very appreciated.

Comment: "so far I have tried this" you cannot assign a `ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>` to a `List<List<?>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the types of the inner lists have nothing in common, there is no way to narrow it down, and the wildcard `?` is the best you can do.

If `T1` `T2` and `T3` all extend from a base class `B`, then you can write:

```
List<List<? extends B>> outerList = new ArrayList<List<? extends B>>();
```

Or likewise if they share an interface. It depends on what common functionality they are implementing that requires them to be stored in the same list.

If you want help with the design you will need to explain your situation with an example/use case. It's probably not good design to keep them in the same collection if they have nothing in common.

Comment: Yes they have nothing in common so I guess my design is bad.

Comment: @Sujen: of course, they always have Object as a base class, so you can always use `List<List<?>>`, but then you can't do anything with the stuff inside. The more important question is what you plan to do with the elements

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Generic information is only available at compile time. However, the exact contents and structure of a list of lists will not be known until runtime. Thus, the compiler, cannot make any assurances about what each list will contain. If you do know in advance the structure of the list then it would be better to consider a holding class eg.

```
class Holder<T,S> {
    List<T> listOfTs;
    List<S> listOfSs;
}
```

If you know that the lists will all share a common supertype then you may wish to use wildcard bounding.

```
List<List<? extends Shape>> list = new ArrayList<List<? extends Shape>>();
list.add(new ArrayList<Circle>());
list.add(new ArrayList<Square>());
```

This will allow you to manipulate the lists according to their supertype. The problem with wildcard bounding is that you cannot add any elements to wildcard bounded collections.

Consider the following:

```
List<? extends Shape> list = new ArrayList<Circle>();
list.add(new Square()); 
// element is a valid shape, but not a valid circle 
// contract of the original list is broken.
```

If you know you are only ever going to use a certain number of generics you could store the class that each represents and use this to cast the lists in a type safe way.

```
class ListHolder<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final List<T> list;

    public ListHolder(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public boolean isCircleList() {
        return this.clazz == Circle.class;
    }

    public List<Circle> getCircleList() {
        if (!isCircleList()) {
             throw new IllegalStateException("list does not contain circles");
        }
        return (List<Circle>) list;
    }

    public boolean isRectangleList() {
        return this.clazz == Rectangle.class;
    }

    public List<Rectangle> getRectangleList() {
        if (!isRectangleList()) {
             throw new IllegalStateException("list does not contain rectangles");
        }
        return (List<Rectangle>) list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListHolder<Rectangle> rectangleListHolder = new ListHolder<Rectangle>(Rectangle.class );

        List<ListHolder<? extends Shape>> list = new ArrayList<ListHolder<? extends Shape>>();

        list.add(rectangleListHolder);

        ListHolder<? extends Shape> shapeWildCardList = list.get(0);

        List<Rectangle> rectangles = shapeWildCardList.getRectangleList();
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot add an `ArrayList<Circle>` to a `List<? extends Shape>`. also `new ListArray<? extends Shape>()` is not valid Java syntax

Comment: @newacct Thanks for pointing that out. I think I got mixed up with just demonstrating wildcard bounding and storing list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed number of types which could go into such lists you could create a subtype for each of those types. This would also have the advantage that you could use instanceof to determine the type of your list, which you probably want to do if you have a list of differently typed lists.

```
// common supertype for the lists
abstract class SpecialList<T> extends LinkedList<T> {}

// a list for every type:
class T1List extends SpecialList<T1> {}
class T2List extends SpecialList<T2> {}
class T3List extends SpecialList<T3> {}


//use
List<SpecialList<?>> l = new ArrayList<SpecialList<?>>();
```

Comment: This seems like an antipattern. If anything `SpecialList` could just be made type-aware by passing the `Class` object of the type into its constructor and setting it to a public final field.

Comment: what's the point of using `SpecialList<?>` instead of just `LinkedList<?>`

Comment: A LinkedList can be a List of any kind, for example LinkedList<Object> whereas a SpecialList can only be a T1List (which only contains T1-Objects), a T2List or a T3List.